# Mysql query to count number of rows with value with a group

Tags: mysql

I have a list of stock ordered by a number of users. i need to know how many of the stock are labeled priority = 'Y' and 'N'

```
SELECT
glidemedia.glide_outlet.run,
glidemedia.glide_stock.title,
glidemedia.glide_stock.stockID,
glidemedia.glide_stock.titleID,
glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem,
count(glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.stockID) as stockCount,
count(glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem = 'Y') as priorityItemYes,
count(glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem = 'N') as priorityItemNo
FROM
glidemedia.glide_outlet
INNER JOIN glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry ON glidemedia.glide_outlet.outletID = glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.outletID
INNER JOIN glidemedia.glide_stock ON glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.stockID = glidemedia.glide_stock.stockID
WHERE
glidemedia.glide_outlet.run = 109
GROUP BY
glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.stockID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
count(glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem = 'Y') as priorityItemYes,
count(glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem = 'N') as priorityItemNo
```

to

```
sum(glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem = 'Y') as priorityItemYes,
sum(glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem = 'N') as priorityItemNo
```

For ANSI standard its

```
sum( 
 case when glidemedia.glide_schedule_entry.priorityItem = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end
) as priorityItemYes
```

**UPDATE**
Why `sum()` instead of `count()`, the reason is you are not counting the number of rows rather you are counting the sum/number of times certain column value is appearing using some condition.